# Count how many times a sublist is in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to know how many times a sublist is in a list next to eachother.

From another question, I received the following code to determinate if a sublist is in a list:

```
list_sequence = ['Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16']

my_list = ['Example 128', 'Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16', 'Example 256', 'Example 512', 'Example 1024']

print(str(list_sequence)[1:-1] in str(my_list))
```

But I want to know, how many times the `list_sequence` is NEXT to each other to determinate a combo. In the top example its 1, but if I would append `list_sequence` at the start and at the very end, it still would 1. If I would add it right after Example 16 in `my_list`, it would be 2.

Comment: Never use Python's built-in keywords as your variable names.

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `enumerate` within a list comprehension to find the respective indices of places where your `sub_list` occurs. Then select those who's subtraction is equal to 3 (length of sub_list):

```
In [6]: list_sequence = ['Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16']
   ...: 
   ...: my_list = ['Example 128', 'Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16', 'Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16', 'Example 256', 'Example 512', 'E
   ...: xample 1024','Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16']
   ...: 

In [7]: indices = [index for index, (i, j, k) in enumerate(zip(my_list, my_list[1:], my_list[2:])) if list_sequence == [i, j, k]]
Out[7]: [1, 4, 10]

In [8]: sum(2 * (j-i == len(list_sequence)) for i, j in zip(indices, indices[1:]))
Out[8]: 2
```

You an only use a generator expression within `sum` to find the number of occurrences:

```
In [4]: sum(list_sequence == [i, j, k] for i, j, k in zip(my_list, my_list[1:], my_list[2:]))
Out[4]: 1
```

But note that this will also include overlaps because `zip(my_list, my_list[1:], my_list[2:]))` will give you all consequent triples.

Answer (score 0):

Count By creating dictionary of list_sequence

```
list_sequence = ['Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16']

my_list = ['Example 128', 'Example 64', 'Example 32', 'Example 16','Example 16', 'Example 256', 'Example 512', 'Example 1024']
dic=dict()
for i in list_sequence :
    for j in my_list :
        if i==j:
            dic[i]=dic.get(i,0)+1
print(dic)
```

> {'Example 64': 1, 'Example 32': 1, 'Example 16': 2}